# Marshmallow permission in custom adapter class

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-permissions

Getting this exception while trying to make a phone call on RecyclerView item click...

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
    Process: com.itec.kdaportal, PID: 11701
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.PackageManager android.content.Context.getPackageManager()' on a null object reference
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageManager(ContextWrapper.java:97)
    at android.app.Activity.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Activity.java:4229)
    at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatApi23.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(ActivityCompatApi23.java:50)
    at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(ActivityCompat.java:419)
    at com.itec.kdaportal.Adapters.DirCustomAdapter$ViewHolder$1.onClick(DirCustomAdapter.java:65)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5716)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22596)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7331)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

The code which is causing this excaption, I think, is here...

```
// Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
public DirCustomAdapter(Context context, Activity activity, ArrayList<Directories> dir) {
    mContext = context;
    mActivity = activity;
    this.list = dir;
}

// Provide a reference to the views for each data item
// Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
// you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    Directories dirObj;
    // each data item is just a string in this case
    public TextView org, contact;
    private int PHONE_PERMISSION_CODE = 03;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        org = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvOrganization);
        contact = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvContactNo);

        v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, dirObj.getOrgName() + " clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                phoneNo = dirObj.getContactNo();
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                        mContext.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:" + dirObj.getContactNo())));
                    }else{
                        if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(mActivity, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)){
                            Toast.makeText(mContext, "App requires Phone Call permission.\nPlease allow that in the device settings.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mActivity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, PHONE_PERMISSION_CODE);
                    }
                }else{
                    mContext.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:" + dirObj.getContactNo())));
                }
            }
        });
    }
    public void bindData(Directories c){
        dirObj = c;
        org.setText(c.getOrgName());
        contact.setText(c.getContactNo());
    }
}
```

Creating CustomAdapter object this way...

```
   dirAdapter = new DirCustomAdapter(this, new DirectoryActivity(), arrayList);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(dirAdapter);
```

App is working fine on pre-Marshmallow devices.

Please help me in fixing it.

Also suggest please, is there any other way to ask for Marshmallow permissions by clicking on RecyclerView item click?

Thanks and Regards

Comment: Try this it may be work stackoverflow.com/a/41221852/5488468

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a new object of Activity class is wrong way.

```
dirAdapter = new DirCustomAdapter(this, new DirectoryActivity(), arrayList); // HERE new DirectoryActivity() is incorrect way to pass Activity reference.
 mRecyclerView.setAdapter(dirAdapter);
```

Use below code

```
dirAdapter = new DirCustomAdapter(this, DirectoryActivity.this, arrayList);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(dirAdapter);
```

I assumed here that, you are calling above code snippet from `DirectoryActivity.java` `Activity` class.

Comment: Yes, It worked.
I was thinking DirectoryActivity.this would pass context.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Although you can use Activity instance only here. No need to pass Context and Activity both.